# String filtering

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a Java like Groovy script, using for Jenkins Pipelines.

In there I have the following scenario.
There's a ArrayList with Strings, specifying versions of a script, such as:

```
def version_list = [] as ArrayList<String>
-> [Version-2.5.0.0, Version-2.4.0.0, Version-2.3.1.0, Version-2.3.0.0, Version-2.0.0.0]
```

This list is fixed and cannot be modified.
I am iterating over the list to get each element, to do some processing.

Additionally I need to check for each element, if there is a point release of the same version i.e.:

```
   version_list.each{each_version -> //each_version = Version-2.3.0.0
                    if(version_list.contains(2.3.x.0)){ //while x!=0
                       print("Version " + each_version + "has point_release")
                    }
                }
```

I already tried the following, but this is not working.

```
 def version_list = [] as ArrayList<String>
 def splitted_ver = [] as ArrayList<String>
 
 version_list.each{each_version ->
                        splitted_ver = each_version.split("\\.")
                        if (version_list.contains("^" + splitted_ver[0] + "." +  splitted_ver[1] + "(.([1-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\$)")){
                            print(each_version + " has a point_release!")   
                        }else{
                            print("has no point_release")
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what is not working and what is the expected result... Please edit your question and add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're going for something like this

```
//example list
def version_list = ["Version-2.2.0.0","Version-2.2.1.0","Version-2.1.1.0","Version-2.1.0.0","Version-2.3.0.0"]
//group by version first 2 digits
def ver_map = version_list.groupBy{ ver -> ver.substring(8,11) }

ver_map.each{ k, v ->
    //prints the lowest (root) version in each set, 
    //then determines if any has point version
    println new StringBuilder().append(v.min{it}).append(" ").append(v.any{ 
        it.matches("^Version\\-([0-9])\\.([0-9])\\.([1-9])\\.([0-9])\$")} 
            ? "has a point release!" : "has no point release")}
```

In this example, prints out

```
Version-2.2.0.0 has a point release!
Version-2.1.0.0 has a point release!
Version-2.3.0.0 has no point release
```

Comment: The point is, that I need to search through the list again to see if there is another entry starting with the same numbers. 

So when splitting as suggested I get [, 3, 0, 0] in case of each_version = Version-2.3.0.0
Now I need to check if there is another entry in the list matching with Version-2.3.[1-9].0

Comment: @AngeloUitz I updated my answer with a new solution. I was having some issues trying to use your regex string, so I expanded it to evaluate the whole string.